# Problems associated with having 50 million rows in database

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I am looking at buying a location data set with 50 million records. What are some of the issues I will face with having a database with this many entries? I plan on using Postgres on heroku. Will I have issues running queries like nearby locations using lat lng? How can I get these queries to run really fast? What are some of the costs associated with this on heroku?

Comment: Vague to the point of uselessness. What access patterns and what indexes? What sort of concurrency? How much are you spending?

Comment: Size doesn't matter, it's what you do with it. And 50 million records isn't that much, I would be worried if our database had only 50 million records!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues come in different flavors. This is a pretty broad question at this point.
First of all you will need to well define the access patterns your app will support. You will need to build a indices on the fields that are used in your where clauses to support those cases. Without indexes, concurrent queries, even only a few dozen, could crush you machine.

As for the geospatial queries in PostGIS, you will also need to create spatial indexes on that data using the lat lon vals of each record to build a point geometry to fill a geometry field. Having a geometry field with a spatial index will make the spatial queries very fast.

Another way to help with speed of access is to use table partitioning, and have each table's datafile on separate mountpoints, where the partitions are based on some location (like a geohash prefix range or something). This is pretty advanced stuff, you'd need to do a lot of reading to implement this unless you have a lot of dba/geo experience.

Regardless, if you expect very high concurrency, you will need a very beefy box.
Alternately, if your use case is essentially read-only, you could use something like Apache SOLR Cloud or ElasticSearch to support you queries, including the point geometry queries, and BBox, and polygon queries. ElasticSearch is clustered, so it will help distribute queries via sharding etc. SOLR Cloud will do the same (essentially). I develop against a 10 node ElasticSearch cluster right now with 750 Million records, each being a geographic point plus a bunch of other fields. These are heavy duty alternatives that might not be necessary if your use case is not one where you have high concurrency, and heavy write load at the same time. Also, if you need to use all the postGis analytic functions, the st_* functions, then you may need to stick with PostGIS anyway.

I know nothing about heroku

HTH

Comment: I'm not sure any of this is particularly true without numbers rather than terms like "very high" or "very fast". To be fair though, the questioner hasn't provided any useful information

Comment: @RichardHuxton and even numbers wouldnt make sense unless we really understand what each record looks like and how many are returned generally per query etc etc... my answer is at the same level of abstraction as the question. I actually think for people just trying to figure out where to start this isn't a bad answer

Comment: @markg no this answer is fantastic and exactly what I was looking for! I can't share too much info on the exact queries we'd be using but for now this is what I needed.. just different things to consider when doing this